# UI mobile tests - which would be the best tool for a project with compose functions and one activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

trying to figure out which is the best tool to create mobile automation tests for a project that uses compose functions written in Kotlin in Android studio
Have to mention that we want the tests to be like end user flows, login + start working in different menus.
Any ideas??
Also if you have a link for some tutorials

Started with espresso but it does not seem to work

Comment: Did you already look at the documentation? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing

Comment: Started looking at it but the problem is that my app uses microsoft login and the jetpack compose framework does not find the elements from the microsoft login pages...however combined UI automater and Jetpack compose and it seems to work ...still having some issues ....just wanted to know if maybe you knew other tools to use beside Jetpack compose

Comment: The problem with Jetpack is that it does not seem to let me continue the flow after login...it redirects me back to initial login page

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit your question and include the test code that you currently have. Then describe the current problem you observe with the testing code you wrote. The way your question is at the moment, it will probably be closed as too broad if you do not edit it.

Comment: Managed to make it work with espresso and UI automator

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work with espresso and UI automator:

- Initiate Main Activity with espresso
- Initiate device with UI automator
- Afterwards, use `findObject` from UI automator and perform clicks and assertions